# reader writer deadlock in sql server

Tags: sql-server

is there any way to avoid deadlock on an update query without changing (or add) the index?

The following query generates always a deadlock

```
update table1
set Batch_ID=1
where item_id in (select top 300 t1.item_id
                        From    table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 on t1.item_id=t2.item_id
                         inner join table3 t3 on t1.item_ID=t3.item_ID
                        Where   IsNull(t3.item_Delivered,0) = 0
                                And t1.TBatch_ID is Null
                                And t2.Shipper_ID = 2
                                And DateDiff(day,t1.TShipping_Date,getdate()) < 90
                                And (
                                        DateDiff(minute,IsNull(t1.LastTrackingDate,DateAdd(day,-2,GetDate())),getdate()) > 180
                                        OR (DateDiff(minute,IsNull(t1.LastTrackingDate,DateAdd(day,-2,GetDate())),getdate()) > 60 And IsNull(t3.item_Indelivery,0) = 1)
                                )
                                    And t2.Customer_ID not in (700,800)
                        Order By    t1.LastTrackingDate, t2.Customer_ID)
```

usually I use `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted` on select query (reader), but in this case it is an update query (writer). So I cannot apply the same reasonning (isolation level).

Is there  a way to set transaction isolation level just for the subquery (just for the select) ??

Can I add WITH (NOLOCK) for each table in the select clause of the subquery ?

Thanks

Comment: An aside, but note that you can avoid the subquery by just joining directly from table.

Comment: StuartLC, how can I avoid the subquery, i.e. how can I do the update only on the top 300 item_id only by joining (without a subquery)??

Comment: Your post doesn't show a top 300 in the subquery? I believe it is is relevant to the issue.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to put it

Answer (score 0):

The query appears to toggle the `Batch_ID` column from NULL to 1 on the first 300 rows which meet a certain criteria.

This update is prone to deadlocks, given that if two connections both run the same query concurrently, both queries will find overlapping `table1` rows and both will try and update (there is a race condition between the rows returned from the subquery and the outer update).

Re : `(NOLOCK)` - no, read uncommitted will lead to even more unpredictable behaviour. One option would be to synchronize concurrent calls to the update by raising the locking pessimism such that any concurrent connection will be blocked until the first connection's batch of 300 has completed tagging, e.g.:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
update table1
set Batch_ID=1
where item_id in (select top 300 t1.item_id
                  From    table1 t1 (WITH XLOCK)  ...
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION READ COMMITTED;
```

Comment: exactly, the application (the same code) run on 4 servers non stop

Comment: However to simplify I put set batch_id=1 in reality it is set batch_id=generatedkey, i.e each time the code run batch_id has a new value it is impossible that 2 batch have the same batch_id value. So I can't see how can using no lock leads to unpredictable behaviour.